# Sort by price in product collection get by magento rest api

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api, web-services, api-filter

I am using below web service to get a product collection sorted by price :

www.magentohost.com/api/rest/products?order=price&dir=asc

It is giving the following error:

> `{"messages":{"error":[{"code":400,"message":"Resource collection ordering error."}]}}`

What is the cause and how can I fix this?

Comment: Where did you get that `order=price&dir=asc` parameters from? I cannot see a function for this on the API documentation page: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/Resources/Products/products.html#RESTAPI-Resource-Products-HTTPMethod-GET-products

Answer (score 1):

The error is thrown in app/code/core/Mage/Api2/Model/Resource.php

```
 if (!is_string($orderField)
     || !array_key_exists($orderField, $this->getAvailableAttributes($this->getUserType(), $operation))
 ) {
     $this->_critical(self::RESOURCE_COLLECTION_ORDERING_ERROR);
 }
```

So I think your `$orderField` is either not a string or the attribut is not available for your operation.

Following back the code from the above function, it retrieves the attributes from the modules `resources/' . $node . '/attributes` XML nodes such as `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/api2.xml`.

`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/api2.xml` for example has a definition of:

```
  <config>
     <api2>
        <resources>
           <product> <!-- your $node -->
              <attributes translate="..." module="api2">
                    <entity_id>Product ID</entity_id>
                    <type_id>Product Type</type_id>
                    <attribute_set_id>Attribute Set</attribute_set_id>
                    <stock_data>Inventory Data</stock_data>
                    <image_url>Default Image</image_url>
                    <is_saleable>Salability Status</is_saleable>
                    <total_reviews_count>Total Reviews Count</total_reviews_count>
                    <url>Product URL</url>
                    <buy_now_url>Buy Now URL</buy_now_url>
                    <has_custom_options>Has Custom Options</has_custom_options>
                    <is_in_stock>Stock Status</is_in_stock>
                    <regular_price_with_tax>Regular Price With Tax</regular_price_with_tax>
                    <regular_price_without_tax>Regular Price Without Tax</regular_price_without_tax>
                    <final_price_with_tax>Final Price With Tax</final_price_with_tax>
                    <final_price_without_tax>Final Price Without Tax</final_price_without_tax>
                    <use_config_gift_message_available>Use Config Settings for Allow Gift Message</use_config_gift_message_available>
                    <use_config_gift_wrapping_available>Use Config Settings for Allow Gift Wrapping</use_config_gift_wrapping_available>
                    <url_key_create_redirect>Create Permanent Redirect for old URL</url_key_create_redirect>
                </attributes>
           </product>
        </resources>
     </api2>
  </config>
```

As I do not see a `price` in there, I think that's the reason why you get the error.

Comment: okay great.Error is resolved now.

Comment: Great! Would you please add your own answer how you resolved your problem to help future readers?

Answer (score 1):

in app/code/core/Mage/api2/Model/Resource.php
_applyCollectionModifiers function need to be editted
below is the edited new code. This solves my problem

```
if (null !== $orderField) {
        $operation = Mage_Api2_Model_Resource::OPERATION_ATTRIBUTE_READ;
        if (!is_string($orderField)
            || !array_key_exists($orderField, $this->getAvailableAttributes($this->getUserType(), $operation))
        ) {
            $this->_critical(self::RESOURCE_COLLECTION_ORDERING_ERROR);
        }
        if("price" == $orderField){
            $dir = $this->getRequest()->getOrderDirection();
            return $collection->getSelect()->order("price_index.min_price {$dir}");
        }
        $collection->setOrder($orderField, $this->getRequest()->getOrderDirection());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added two lines in /app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Api2/Product/Rest.php file in 
function "_prepareProductForResponse" after line  $product->setCustomerGroupId($this->_getCustomerGroupId()).

```
protected function _prepareProductForResponse(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product)
{
    /** @var $productHelper Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product */
    $productHelper = Mage::helper('catalog/product');
    $productData = $product->getData();
    $product->setWebsiteId($this->_getStore()->getWebsiteId());
    // customer group is required in product for correct prices calculation
    $product->setCustomerGroupId($this->_getCustomerGroupId());
    // calculate prices
    $finalPrice = $product->getFinalPrice();
    $productData['price'] = $finalPrice;
    $productData['regular_price_with_tax'] = $this->_applyTaxToPrice($product->getPrice(), true);
    $productData['regular_price_without_tax'] = $this->_applyTaxToPrice($product->getPrice(), false);
    $productData['final_price_with_tax'] = $this->_applyTaxToPrice($finalPrice, true);
    $productData['final_price_without_tax'] = $this->_applyTaxToPrice($finalPrice, false);
    $productData['is_saleable'] = $product->getIsSalable();
    $productData['image_url'] = (string) Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image');
    $productData['small_image'] = (string) Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(225,300);

    if ($this->getActionType() == self::ACTION_TYPE_ENTITY) {

        // define URLs
        $productData['url'] = $productHelper->getProductUrl($product->getId());
        /** @var $cartHelper Mage_Checkout_Helper_Cart */
        $cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
        $productData['buy_now_url'] = $cartHelper->getAddUrl($product);

        /** @var $stockItem Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item */
        $stockItem = $product->getStockItem();
        if (!$stockItem) {
            $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
            $stockItem->loadByProduct($product);
        }
        $productData['is_in_stock'] = $stockItem->getIsInStock();

        /** @var $reviewModel Mage_Review_Model_Review */
        $reviewModel = Mage::getModel('review/review');
        $productData['total_reviews_count'] = $reviewModel->getTotalReviews($product->getId(), true,
            $this->_getStore()->getId());

        $productData['tier_price'] = $this->_getTierPrices();
        $productData['has_custom_options'] = count($product->getOptions()) > 0;
    } else {
        // remove tier price from response
        $product->unsetData('tier_price');
        unset($productData['tier_price']);
    }
    $product->addData($productData);
}
```

and the problem is resolevd.Price is coming in product collection.